# Auto increment doesn't work, with two fields unique on Loopback

Tags: mysql, loopback

I works on Loopback and have automigration works fine. But, I need config a model with two unique identifiers.

With this config

```
 "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "Number",
      "id": true,
      "generated": true, // doesn't works
      "required": false
    },
    "verificationCode": {
      "type": "String",
      "required": true,
      "id": true,
      "length": 10,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "verification_code"
      }
    },
```

ID = is primary key, is not AUTO INCREMENT

VerificationCode = is primary key

Any idea? thanks

Comment: what `datasources` are you using ? According to my understanding, id injection can only be used to one field. If you are using `mysql` or `postgres` then id will be automatically incremented.

Comment: Your are right, but, How I can define another "unique" field in my model?

Answer (score 0):

you can keep multiple keys in loopback using numbering the id element as follow
"id": 1, "id": 2
, and you can just keep another unique key using 
validatesUniquenessOf()
 method in your js file

Comment: In my case my primary key's data type is an integer and is auto-incrementing as defaults of loopback, the unique key is just a unique key that we can't create a duplicate entry for the database ...